# SVG Path rotation animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to get part of my SVG to rotate, but it seems like it's rotating around an extremely large origin, which is confusing because the actual path is incredibly small.

Here is my path element animation css:

```
.wing1 {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  animation: spin 6s cubic-bezier(.8, 0, .2, 1) infinite;
  @keyframes spin {
    50% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  }
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle (with the SVG included): http://jsfiddle.net/c5g3sq4e/

I'm trying to get the wing element to rotate around the bottom right corner so that it looks like it's flying, but I've never done SVG element rotation so I'm not sure  that I've specified the origin correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `transform-box: fill-box;` This will make the object bounding box to be used as the reference box.

```css
.wing1 {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation: spin 6s cubic-bezier(.8, 0, .2, 1) infinite;
  @keyframes spin {
    50% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  }
}
```

Comment: `transform-box` is a recent thing.  If you want to be compatible with older browser versions, consider using absolute coordinates instead. Eg. `transform-origin: 736px -124px;`

Comment: `transform-box` is a recent thing used to fix another recent thing. This pen: https://codepen.io/mandymichael/details/LEpywo (as the author comment) used to work best in chrome. Not any longer. Back in 2014-2015 this pen worked without `transform-box`. Now you would need `transform-box` to make it work properly.

Comment: Not exactly. That Chrome behaviour was a bug.  Which they have now fixed. `transform-box` was added to provide flexibility in how to interpret `transform-origin`.  Your fix will work now in most browsers. But it won't work in a Firefox from a year ago - with or without `transform-box`. My suggestion will work in all versions of Chrome and Firefox.